# Tracking string of text in memory

Tags: c#, c++, memory

I have a program that reads certain information from another program, from memory. The program I am monitoring, basically outputs a continuously expanding amount of text. I would like my program to replicate this text in its UI. Syntax wise, coding all of this was fine, but I am struggling with how I can logically solve it, given the text's behavior in memory. Below follows the information I have found in memory, and how the string behaves.

**This is the information I have:**

1. A memory pointer to the start of the string segment
2. A memory pointer to the byte that follows after the last byte that was written
3. A memory pointer to an int that tells us how many bytes there is, been the two above

Now what I initially did was to store how many bytes I had read, then with a timer that fired every 2 seconds, just read the bytes between what I last read and the end (as is implied by pointer 3).

The above approach crashed after a random period of time, because after a random number of bytes has been written, the string segment actually wraps and starts to write from top again (location that pointer 1 points to), overwriting what was there before. Pointer 2 and 3 gets updated when this happens, so that is fine, but I am still not able to figure out how I should solve it.

**I have thought about this potential approaches, but found it to be erroneous:** When polling, before making any other calculations, check if the bytes I have read so far is larger than the number of bytes shown in 3. If it is, then set number of bytes read to 0, and start from top again. Problem with this approach is that I might miss something at bottom of the string segment, if something is written at bottom, then quickly another thing is written that makes the string wrap, before I had the chance to spot it.

Any thoughts, insight tips, or solutions, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a way to attach yourself to the memory and get warned when certain parts are being requested or written to. the event might fire to late but it's good enough to try. Can't recall if it was a third party dll, windows dll or .net feature but i used to do it 6-7 years ago. Someone else might remember what it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest thing to do is to have the Reader process read the full contents of the shared memory every time. Then display the entirety of the text in the UI. There is no need to have a "cursor".

The next easiest thing to do is read the full contents of the shared memory, but have the Reader process keep a copy of the last bunch of text it read. Then after every read, it compares the text to cache text to determine if anything changes. Still no need for cursors.

I would recommend using a more robust way to share data between the processes, if possible. Eventually, you will run into problems synchronizing the two processes. In the end you will write an inter-process communication framework. I think some simple implementation of an inter-process message queue would be ideal for this kind of application.

Comment: ahoffer, that's a really helpful answer. I actually thought of both your two suggestions, but then had the following questions: 1) Is it really slow and inefficient to read and display everything each time, when the text becomes very large? 2) For the comparison-approach, is there a good way to compare very large string segments? 3) The key problem i see now though, is that i cannot really copy the full text each time, because some of it has been overwritten (after it wraps and starts from top). If i read all, then I eventually loose the first part of the text. What do you think?

Comment: I think what you want is a circular buffer for IPC. I googled it and found some examples, but I do not know which example fits your case. A Google search on circular buffer or rung buffer pulls up lots of single process examples, which actually might be a good place to start.

Comment: Comparing text to find out where things left is possible, but feels like a hack. How much text are we talking about? If you need to do it quickly, use hashes. Make a hash table where each line of text is a key. Then check to see if the key exists-- if the key doesn't exist, you have found a new line of text.

Comment: There will eventually be a lot of text, like book-length. Another level of complexity is that lines can be identical